# EC2 - Log into self w/o a key or password

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I would like to be able to `ssh` into my node and then run software that for its own purposes, `ssh`'s into other machines and itself. It assumes that `ssh` keys are set up already so it cannot take the `-i` flag and use that.

I have a working Xen setup where this works fine: all I had to do was scp my private key to `.ssh/id_rsa` and the public part to `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (which I can recover in EC2 since it's in `.ssh/authorized_keys`).

This same setup simply doesn't work in EC2. I've verified that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` are the same on my Xen box that works and the EC2 box that does not.

The base AMI I'm using is `ami-1774927e`, the Alestic.com image containing a fresh Ubuntu Hardy install. Naturally, port 22 is open in my security group for `ssh` traffic.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Based on womble's advise and advise on the Amazon EC2 forums, here's extra information that may be helpful:

`sshd_config` and `ssh_config` are the same on my Xen and EC2 boxes (and are the default ones shipped with the Alestic ami specified earlier), and I'm not using any command line options. `ssh-agent` isn't running, and there are no other `ssh` keys on the machine. I'm only logging in as root, and **most importantly**, I can log into my EC2 box from the same box if I use -i  when the keyname isn't `id_rsa`.

When I use the -i  flag, the tail end of ssh -v looks like this:

```
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ec2scale.key
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Mon Jul  6 23:42:49 2009 from 127.0.0.1
Linux (none) 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:34:28 EST 2008 x86_64
... and so on ...
```

But when I don't use the -i flag, I get this:

```
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've `diff`'ed the keys and they are identical, and I can see that the server accepts my id_rsa key above but just that the auth doesn't go through. Checking out `/var/log/auth.log` shows just this when I log in:

```
Jul  6 23:46:09 ip-10-244-50-159 sshd[1354]: error: RSA_public_decrypt failed: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106)
```

Which I can use `openssl` to see the error code of:

```
root@ip:~# openssl errstr 0407006A
error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
```

But I'm not sure how I can use that to help my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much work on the Amazon EC2 forum, the "solution" was to simply name the key anything other than `id_rsa`. Since the only other keyname that could be used that would be taken automatically was `id_dsa`, I named the key that and it worked. [This thread](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=134532#134532) shows the steps taken to debug the problem, which are reproduced here in case a future reader runs into similar problems.

- contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
- contents of `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- contents of `$HOME/.ssh/config`
- permissions of directories and files
- command line options you are using (e.g., `-I` and `-A`)
- user names you are using
- `SSH_*` environment variables
- `ssh-agent` status and what keys have been `ssh-add`'ed
- `ssh -v -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa <REMOTE>`
- `ssh -v <REMOTE>`
- `strace ssh -v -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa <REMOTE>`
- ran `sshd` with the [debug flag `-d`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd)
- resolved by copying `id_rsa` to `id_dsa`, ensure there is no `id_dsa.pub` (or it won't work)

Answer (score 1):

Well, without the contents of the auth logs to see what the SSH server thinks is going on, and the output of a verbose run of the SSH client, the only guess I can offer is that something is misconfigured.

EDIT: So, unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can login to the EC2 machines fine, except when you don't use the correct key?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check it out. Do you know the usual location of where the auth logs are stored?

Comment: /var/log/auth.log by default on Debian-based systems.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. I've updated the post with more info based on that, and I can confirm that it happens on other Xen boxes, so it's not just an EC2 thing.